# MySql insert 0 instead of my value

Tags: php, mysql, insert

when I try to send this query in MySQL, it does not work.

**This is the query:**

```sql
INSERT INTO odds_table 
(ID, 
DataOra, 
League, 
TeamHome, 
TeamAway, 
SpreadNowHome, 
SpreadNowAway, 
OddsNowHome, 
OddsNowAway, 
SpreadOpenHome, 
SpreadOpenAway, 
OddsOpenHome, 
OddsOpenAway, 
TotalLineNow, 
TotalLineOpen, 
OverNow, 
UnderNow, 
OverOpen, 
UnderOpen) 
VALUES 
(NULL, 
DataOra='25/02/2018 16:00', 
League='Belgium First Division B', 
TeamHome='KFCO Beerschot Wilrijk', 
TeamAway='Lierse SK', 
SpreadNowHome='-0.5', 
SpreadNowAway='0.5', 
OddsNowHome='1.82', 
OddsNowAway='2.08', 
SpreadOpenHome='-0.5', 
SpreadOpenAway='0.5', 
OddsOpenHome='1.85', 
OddsOpenAway='1.99', 
TotalLineNow='2.5', 
TotalLineOpen='2.5', 
OverNow='1.90', 
UnderNow='1.98', 
OverOpen='1.96', 
UnderOpen='1.86')
```

**In the php it is inserted like this:**

```php
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO odds_table (ID, DataOra, League, TeamHome, TeamAway, SpreadNowHome, SpreadNowAway, OddsNowHome, OddsNowAway, SpreadOpenHome, SpreadOpenAway, OddsOpenHome, OddsOpenAway, TotalLineNow, TotalLineOpen, OverNow, UnderNow, OverOpen, UnderOpen) VALUES (NULL, DataOra='$DataOra', League='$League', TeamHome='$TeamHome', TeamAway='$TeamAway', SpreadNowHome='$SpreadNowHome', SpreadNowAway='$SpreadNowAway', OddsNowHome='$OddsNowHome', OddsNowAway='$OddsNowAway', SpreadOpenHome='$SpreadOpenHome', SpreadOpenAway='$SpreadOpenAway', OddsOpenHome='$OddsOpenHome', OddsOpenAway='$OddsOpenAway', TotalLineNow='$TotalLineNow', TotalLineOpen='$TotalLineOpen', OverNow='$OverNow', UnderNow='$UnderNow', OverOpen='$OverOpen', UnderOpen='$UnderOpen')");
```

I have tried other solutions but nothing worked.
The values with the float numbers in the table is decimal(5,2).
How could I solve?

Ps. The single peak is not the problem.

Comment: You're using UPDATE syntax in VALUES.

Comment: You’re right, I made a stupid mistake ahahah

Comment: Mistakes happen and that's why we're here ;-) *ciao, e piano piano!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using UPDATE syntax in VALUES without "SET" which would be valid.

Either you add the SET method, or remove all instances of `Column_name='$variable'` and replace them with just `'$variable'`.

Side note: Should there be any characters that MySQL will complain about, one such as an apostrophe, then you will need to escape it, since that would be an SQL injection right there. In either case, you should parametrize your query.

Examples from the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html:

Using standard INSERT/VALUES:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    [(col_name [, col_name] ...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} (value_list) [, (value_list)] ...
    [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE assignment_list]
```

Using "SET":

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    SET assignment_list
    [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE assignment_list]
```

However, you should use a prepared statement if you're not already doing so.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Using `mysqli_error($con)` would have shown you the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query

```
INSERT INTO odds_table (ID, DataOra, League, TeamHome, TeamAway, 
SpreadNowHome, SpreadNowAway, OddsNowHome, OddsNowAway, SpreadOpenHome, 
SpreadOpenAway, OddsOpenHome, OddsOpenAway, TotalLineNow, TotalLineOpen, 
OverNow, UnderNow, OverOpen, UnderOpen) VALUES (NULL, '25/02/2018 16:00', 
'Belgium First Division B', 'KFCO Beerschot Wilrijk', 'Lierse SK', '-0.5', 
'0.5', '1.82', '2.08', '-0.5', '0.5', '1.85', '1.99', '2.5', '2.5', '1.90', 
'1.98', '1.96', '1.86')
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sometime i gave the answer from the cell phone so not provide the brief description. Also i will consider your things in the future post. Thanks